# Как сопоставить элементы списков и вернуть словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется 2 списка, элеметов в них одинаковое количество. Надо сопоставить элементы списков и вернуть  словарь. Пример:

```
[1, 2, 3], ["1", "2", "3"] => {1:"1", 2:"2", 3:"3"}
```

Comment: Передаете оба списка в функцию zip, она будет возвращать элементы попарно. Потом эти пары как ключи и значения собираете в словарь (в принципе это одной строкой без циклов через `dict(zip(l1, l2))` делается)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, 3 дня думал как это сделать, про zip знал, но не знал, что оно делает, просто проект делаю, каждый день над ним сижу, голова уже кипит.